# How to avoid overlapped rules

Tags: clips

I'm running clipsrules Version 6.40 Beta and I have two overlapped rules e.g.

```
(defrule cluster03
 (and (x ?x & :(> ?x -1.16)) (y ?y & :(> ?y 2.77)))
=>
 (assert (cluster 0))
```

and

```
(defrule cluster23
 (and (x ?x & :(<= ?x 0.91)) (y ?y & :(> ?y 1.35)))
=>
 (assert (cluster 2))
```

It is obvious that point (x,y)->(0,4) match both rules (cluster 0 and 2) and that solution is generated by clipsrules (first fire indicates cluster 0 and second fire indicates cluster 2) but according to dataset, this point should be assigned to cluster 0. Is there any solution to obtain just one output in clipsrules?

Answer (score 0):

You need a rule for handling ambiguous cases. For example, if more than one cluster is assigned, pick the one with the lowest value:

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule multiple-clusters
   (cluster ?c1)
   ?c <- (cluster ?c2&:(> ?c2 ?c1))
   =>
   (retract ?c))
CLIPS> (assert (cluster 0) (cluster 2))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (cluster 0)
f-2     (cluster 2)
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      multiple-clusters: f-1,f-2
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (cluster 0)
For a total of 1 fact.
CLIPS>
```